# How can I make indentations and then align at different levels, in a table?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, indentation

How do I create this table? It is the subtle indentations that are throwing me. I know I'm missing something simple.

[image: table example]

Comment: You should post the code you have so far (the basic table in a complete, compilable document), so not everyone has to reproduce it, and you should include information on what you've already tried.

Comment: I'll do that in the future. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a `tabbing` environment. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing}
\quad\=\quad\=One $= 0$ the other $\neq 0$\quad
  \=Whole line of equilibrium points\kill
\rule{.8\linewidth}{1pt}\\
Eigenvalues\>\>\>Stability\\[-1.2ex]
\rule{.8\linewidth}{1pt}\\
REAL\\
\>Unequal\\
\>\>Both $>0$\>Unstable node (source, repeller)\\
\>\>Both $<0$\>Stable node (sink, attractor)\\
\>\>Different signs\>Saddle point\\
\>\>One $= 0$ the other $\neq 0$\>Whole line of equilibrium points\\
\>Equal\\
\>\>Both $>0$\>Unstable node (source, repeller)\\
\>\>Both $<0$\>Stable node (sink, attractor)\\
\>\>Both $=0$\>Algebraic unstable\\
COMPLEX\\
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

[image: tabbing example]

- `\=` marks a tab stop
- `\>` go to the next tab stop
- `\\` ends a line
- `\kill` ends a line but doesn't print it, useful for a tab stop model line

Answer (score 9):

You could use some defined space for indenting within the table. Consider the example below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{} l l @{}}
  \toprule
  Eigenvalues & Stability\\
  \midrule
  REAL\\
  \hspace{0.25cm} Unequal\\
  \hspace{0.5cm} Both $>0$ & Unstable node (source, repeller)\\
  \hspace{0.5cm} Both $<0$ & Stable node (sink, attractor)\\
  \hspace{0.5cm} Different signs & Saddle point\\
  \hspace{0.5cm} $= 0$ the other $\neq 0$ & Whole line of equilibrium points\\
  ...\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This code renders the following:

[image: Implementation of OP's proposed table.]

**Edit:** Edited code and output image for clarity.

Comment: Or simply `~` for single indentation and `~~` for double.